# Function handling floating point numbers to produce a boolean

Tags: python, floating-point

I've been struggling with the following Boolean problem:

> Write a function even_int that consumes any type of data, produces True if it is an even integer, and produces False otherwise.

I wrote:

```
def even_int(any):
    return type(any) != type("a") and float(any % 2 == 0.0)
```

Feedback on your program:

> Make sure your function works when the input is a floating point number.

Don't really understand this feedback. I put the float in front so that should be covered. I also tried without the float or the decimal on the 0.

Comment: Why do you have at test for strings at the start? What should happen when someone passes in, say, a list?

Comment: You also produce a `float()`, not a boolean. You don't return `True`, you return `1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just directly check if any is an integer type. I also don't think you need to put a float around `any % 2 == 0`

```
def even_int(value):
    return isinstance(value, int) and value % 2 == 0
```

EDIT:
if you want to accept floats as well,

```
def even_int(value):
    return isinstance(value, (float, int)) and value % 2 == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this - it's pythonic in that it asks for forgiveness rather than permission by trying to convert to an int (this means it works for strings as well) and catches the `TypeError` to return False if that doesn't work either.

```
def even_int(v):
    try:
        return int(v) % 2 == 0 #will trigger exception if v cannot be cast to int

    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        return False
```

EDIT: Simplified based on comments

Comment: 1) `any` is not a great choice for a variable name - there's a builtin function called `any` that will shadow (although I realise you're taking that from the OPs code)... 2) Your entire `try` can be `return int(value) % 2 == 0`...

Comment: 1) good point - I was using the OPs variable name:) will change 2) yes I realise that, but was hoping it would be a bit clearer what was happening my way, but will edit to add:)

Comment: actually - another problem - even_int(2.3) returns true as float conversion truncates